# Use existing record in `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with has_one association by passing id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-6

RoR noob here, using Mongoid.

I have a model (ItineraryItem) with `has_one` association which `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

```
class ItineraryItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :title, type: String

  has_one :poi
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poi
end
```

I am able to create a new `ItineraryItem` by passing `poi_attributes`

The following parameter body works for creating new `ItineraryItem` along with `Poi`:

```
{
  "itinerary_item" : {
    "title" : "Itinerary Item With New POI",
    "description" : "Itinerary Item Description",
    "poi_attributes" : {
        "title" : "A New POI in creation"
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not able to create a new `ItineraryItem` with an existing `Poi`

The following **does not work** for me:

```
{
  "itinerary_item" : {
    "title" : "Itinerary Item With New POI",
    "description" : "Itinerary Item Description",
    "poi_attributes" : {
        "id" : "5ea9bdf6b980a78222f71263" # I've made sure this id exists
    }
  }
}
```

The above returns an error

> Poi is invalid

with 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

I am guessing that I am not supposed to associate an existing record of POI as it is one-to-one association, and every `ItineraryItem` should have its own `Poi`.
But I am not sure. Is it being blocked by Rails, or am I missing something?

Comment: Why is poi a `has_one` and not a `belongs_to`?

Comment: @Oleg Because `ItineraryItem` is the parent. poi `belongs_to` itinerary_item

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: @Oleg Because Every ItineraryItem should wrap one poi, not other way around. I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: If "ItineraryItem should wrap one poi", then I expect that itinerary item will belong to poi. I am confused why your association is set up in the direction that it is. This direction as far as I can tell is the cause of your present predicament, so there must be an overriding reason for it being this way.

Answer (score 0):

If `Poi` does have nullable `iternary_item_id` field, it's possible to "reassign" it to another object.

From what you've posted, it looks like you're trying to create a new object via some sort of API controller. Try to run a `rails c`onsole and check if you're able to create a new IternaryItem with a pot id as a nested parameter - it can give you some detailed errors - if you're able to do it, then the problem lays somewhere else, f.e. you need to add `id` to permitted params list of `poi_attributes` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

In internary_items controller add "id" to nested attributes . In your case it would be:

```
params.require(:payload).permit(:iternary_item, :poi_attributes => [:id, :x,:y])
```